# What does it mean to say that a measure is supported on a set?

Tags: measure-theory

What does it mean to say that a **measure $\mu$ is supported on set $E$** ? I keep coming across this phrase, but its meaning is always assumed which can get somewhat confusing.

Does it simply mean that for each (open) neighborhood $N \subset  E$, we have that $\mu(N) \neq 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that for any measurable set $A$, $\mu(A) = \mu(A \cap E)$.

(We can't talk about open neighbourhoods, since our measurable space doesn't necessarily have the structure of a topological space.)

Comment: Thanks.  Indeed, I should have specified that $E$ is assumed to be a topological space.  Is my interpretation equivalent to the definition you gave, in that case?

Comment: Let's consider the measure $\mu$ on $X = \{ 0, 1 \}$ defined by $\mu(\{ 0 \} = 456$, $\mu\{ 1 \} = 0$. And let's put a discrete topology on $\{ 0, 1 \}$. Then $\mu$ is supported on $\{0 \}$. But you could also say that $\mu$ is supported on $\{0, 1 \}$ - that would be true too. And yet, $N  = \{ 1 \}$ is an open subset of $\{ 0, 1 \}$, and $\mu(N) = 0$.